# How do I display every git commits in my web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-3

How can i get all the git commits made within different git branches and make it available in my web application? I am self hosting not using github and the web application is built in Ruby on Rails 3.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Grit](https://github.com/mojombo/grit/)

Comment: thanks it worked but still have one small issue i want to take all branches how could i get them all, any idea?

Comment: This should get you started, but I'm not completely sure what you need      repo = Grit::Repo.new(RAILS_ROOT)  repo.branches.each { |b| repo.commits(b.name)}

Comment: thanks buddy i got it. it is repo.head.each not repo.branches. thanks for your time :)